# Can't run nvidia docker

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

I have struggled in the last couple of days to have my GPU work through VNC. I have finally done it, realizing at the end that my docker is not working anymore when run with GPU. This happens regardless of the VNC server running or not.

```
sudo docker run --rm --gpus all nvidia/cuda:11.0-base nvidia-smi  
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"process_linux.go:432: running prestart hook 0 caused \\\"error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: nvidia-container-cli: initialization error: nvml error: insufficient permissions\\\\n\\\"\"": unknown.
```

Ubuntu 20.04,

Nvidia 418.152 (but I have tried with 455 and 418)

Titan X
`nvidia-smi` output

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.152.00   Driver Version: 418.152.00   CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  TITAN X (Pascal)    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 23%   30C    P8    10W / 250W |     62MiB / 12192MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0       959      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            59MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have installed the `nvidia-container-toolkit` and restarted the daemon. I have also purged docker and reinstalled it. Nothing helped.

Please! Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to solve it. The problem is not in nvidia-docker, the problem is in nvidia-container-toolkit. You need to change the user who execute nvidia-container-toolkit. To do that, you need to uncomment or add
user = "root:video"
in the file located in /etc/nvidia-container-runtime/config.toml

I hope this help.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate the help! It's been a while since I had this problem but I did solve it somehow. But useful to have another solution here :)

Comment: @Vaaal88 Please explain how did you solve it